# How to convert flat values to a JSON with dynamically changing schema?

Tags: java, json, csv, serialization

I have a list of values e.g. in a CSV; and a JSON schema **which can change at runtime**. I want to create a JSON out of the schema and fill appropriate values from the CSV.

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve:

Here is a CSV:

> productId, price, inStock
> 12345, 200, true
> 45678, 299, true

I need to convert each line to a JSON like following, for example. There can be nested objects. The schema can change and i would need to provide relevant mapping.

```
{
  "product":{
    "id": "1234",
    "price" : 200,
    "stockAvailable" : "yes"
  }
}
```

I thought of some ways of achieving it. I wanted to check if there is any better way available via some library. If not, is there any downside to any of the following methods?

---

**1.**
Create a JSON from the schema with a the default value as the mapped column number of the CSV inside curly brackets. Like, in the above example, the JSON like following. The values can be supplied using a String formatter.

```
{
  "product":{
    "id": {0},
    "price" : {1},
    "stockAvailable" : {2}
  }
}
```

---

**2.**
Create a dynamic set of JSON data-binding classes. Fill the values (using Jackson or something like that) and convert to JSON.

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "price", "stock"})
public class Product {

    public String id;
    public Double price;
    public Boolean stock;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use a Map<String, Object> and wrap that into a POJO?

You can also use Jackson Substypes but you need the definitions beforehand
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations